# android java play song, audio, sound file (external SD works but not internal storage)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-external-storage

External storage works, but not internal storage.  Am I missing out on something fundamentally from the android storage mechanism?
thanks

```
public static void playSound()
{
    //String path = internalPath + "/www/sounds/" + "SIREN.WAV"; // doesnt work
    //String path = "file:///data/data/com.myproject.d08062014f/files/www/sounds/SIREN.WAV"; // doesnt work
    //String path = "/data/data/com.myproject.d08062014f/files/www/sounds/SIREN.WAV"; // doesnt work
    // all above does not work
    Log.d("command", "command:" + path); // to check path string
    String path = "file:///mnt/sdcard/media/audio/notifications/facebook_ringtone_pop.m4a"; // This one works!
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

---

Update on 09-10-2014

stackoverflow.com/a/4955915/856007 –  Abdullah Shoaib Aug 12 at 7:49
thank you for the reference link below, I was able to get it working with

```
File file = new File(path); // acquire the file from path string
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: use `String path=Context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();` to get internal storage path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4955915/856007

Comment: permissions? in android manifest?